# Matlab - How to use a matrix to filter another matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would use the column of matrix B, to filter the matrix A using the 3rd column.
Note that the values ​​of the 3rd column are separated by commas.

Example: P01 exist in the 3rd column of the matrix A, then we get the value A1.
Other example: A2 is not returned because P08 or P09 not exist in B.

```
A = {'A1'  5  'P01,P02,P03,P04'; 'A2'  7  'P08,P09'; 'A3'  8  'P07'; 'A4'  8  'P10,P11'};
B = {'P01'; 'P07'; 'P10'; 'P11'}

A = 
   'A1'  5  'P01,P02,P03,P04'
   'A2'  7  'P08,P09'
   'A3'  8  'P07'
   'A4'  8  'P10,P11'

B =
   'P01'
   'P07'
   'P10'
   'P11'
   'P12'
   'P13'
```

How can I obtain this result?

```
C =
   'A1'
   'A3'
   'A4'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: What does this have to do with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aux = cellfun(@(c) A(~cellfun('isempty', strfind(A(:,3), c)), 1), B, 'UniformOutput', 0);
C = unique(vertcat(aux{:}));
```

Comment: I need to get also rows where 'c' equal '1'. I tried this but don't work:  ...cellfun('isempty', strfind(listAllPara(:,3), c) || c == '1')...

Comment: @TimeIsNear I don't see what you mean by "`c` equal `1`". What is `c`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be ok.

```
A = {'A1',  5  'P01,P02,P03,P04'; 
    'A2'  7,  'P08,P09';
    'A3'  8,  'P07';
    'A4'  8,  'P10,P11'};

B = {'P01'; 'P07'; 'P10'; 'P11'};


size(A)

C = {};

% for each row in A
for ai = 1:size(A, 1)

    rowA = A(ai, :);

    firstCol  = rowA{1};
    thirdCol = rowA{3};

    % search if any element of B belongs to string in thirdCol
    searchResult = cellfun(@(bv) ~isempty(findstr(bv, thirdCol)), B, ...
                                         'UniformOutput', false);

    % change results to matrix
    searchResult = cell2mat(searchResult)';


    % if any element of B in thirdCol then add firstCol to C
    if  any(searchResult) == 1
        C{end + 1} = firstCol;
    end

end



C

% gives
C = 

    'A1'
    'A3'
    'A4'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and very nice code, but when I search for "P0" I will get all rows. While result should be empty.